# React w/ Redux - Best way to find matching path in history

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, browser-history

I have a React/Redux project that consists of a navigation, lists of items and a details pane (showing one single item).

[image]

The "Pop hits 2" album can be opened by navigating to path "/list/all" **or** "/list/pop" and then selecting the "Pop hits 2" row. When the "Pop hits 2" opens the path changes to "/album/1234567890". For correct rendering of the UI I need to know where I opened the "Pop hits 2" from ("/list/all" or "/list/pop") when closing the details pane. The album can also be opened from a shared link. I do **not** wish to use history.go(-1) - this will not work when pasting a shared link.

I need to be able to find the actual path in the history that matches the last opened list.

Is there a recommended way to achieve this in React?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out the best way to see where the application has been been is to simply use the state property in the [React Router Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link).

[This article](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/) on how to pass state from Link to components really helped explain how to use the Link state.

Basically the Link can pass the state property to the rendered component.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/courses", state: { fromDashboard: true } }} />
```

The rendered component then access the state via props.location.state

This in conjunction with passing props to components generating the links solved my problem! (^__^)